# Why doesn't giving stickers register in my To Do List in Sims Mobile?

Tags: the-sims-mobile

One of my tasks in my To Do List in Sims Mobile is to give stickers to other players. I've given out plenty of stickers, but only one of them ever registered as having been given. Am I doing something wrong? I want to complete this task.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That was happening to me also. I deleted the tab and waited 10 seconds and it worked.